# Delete many-to-many record in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-8.0, ef-core-8.0

When I am trying to delete a record in the many-to-many table I get following error:

> The property 'CollectionItemDefinition.Id' could not be found. Ensure that the property exists and has been included in the model.

When I am try to define an extra key with name Id then I get this error:

> The given key 'Domain.Models.CollectionItemDefinition' was not present in the dictionary.

Where is the problem with my configuration?

Domain Models:

```
public class Collection
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    public List<ItemDefinition> ItemDefinitions { get; set; } = new();
    public List<CollectionItemDefinition> CollectionItemDefinitions { get; set; } = new();
}

public class CollectionItemDefinition
{
    public Guid CollectionId { get; set; }
    public Guid ItemDefinitionId { get; set; }
    public Collection Collection { get; set; } = null!;
    public ItemDefinition ItemDefinition { get; set; } = null!;
}

public class ItemDefinition
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    public List<Collection> Collections { get; set; } = new();
    public List<CollectionItemDefinition> CollectionItemDefinitions { get; set; } = new();
}
```

Fluent Configurations:

```
public class CollectionConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Collection>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Collection> builder)
    {
         builder.ToTable(nameof(Collection));
         builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
         builder.HasMany(x => x.ItemDefinitions)
            .WithMany(x => x.Collections)
            .UsingEntity<CollectionItemDefinition>(
                r => r.HasOne<ItemDefinition>(x => x.ItemDefinition).WithMany(x => x.CollectionItemDefinitions), 
                l => l.HasOne<Collection>(x => x.Collection).WithMany(x => x.CollectionItemDefinitions));
    }
}

public class CollectionItemDefinitionConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<CollectionItemDefinition>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<CollectionItemDefinition> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable(nameof(CollectionItemDefinition));
    }
}

public class ItemDefinitionConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ItemDefinition>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ItemDefinition> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable(nameof(ItemDefinition));
    }
}
```

Query:

```
var entity = await context.Collections
    .Include(x => x.ItemDefinitions)
    .Include(x => x.CollectionItemDefinitions)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == request.Model.Collection.Id, cancellationToken);

var itemDefinitions = await context.ItemDefinitions
    .Where(x => request.Model.ItemDefinitionIds.Contains(x.Id))
    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

context.CollectionItemDefinitions.RemoveRange(entity.CollectionItemDefinitions);
entity.ItemDefinitions.AddRange(itemDefinitions);

await context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was thrown on a complete different part of my code. I have overwritten the SaveChanges methods and tried to access the "Id" property with this statement entry.Property("Id").CurrentValue. But for the join table i had no "Id" column.